How to display SfChart View annotation on specific datetime?
Here is the rewritten question:

I need to add chart annotations at specific dates dynamically based on the count of a notes list in a Syncfusion chart. While I can bind chart annotations using fixed X1 and Y1 coordinates, I need a dynamic solution.
Here is my code for the ViewModel:
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Data { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<ChartAnnotation> SfChartChartAnnotations { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ChartAnnotation>();
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Data = new ObservableCollection<Model>
        {
            new Model { Name = "Jan", Date = new DateTime(2000, 05, 01), YValue = 10 },
            new Model { Name = "Feb", Date = new DateTime(2000, 06, 01), YValue = 20 },
            new Model { Name = "Mar", Date = new DateTime(2000, 07, 01), YValue = 25 },
            new Model { Name = "Apr", Date = new DateTime(2000, 08, 01), YValue = 20 },
            new Model { Name = "May", Date = new DateTime(2000, 09, 01), YValue = 30 },
            new Model { Name = "May", Date = new DateTime(2000, 10, 01), YValue = 30 }
        };

        ViewAnnotation annotation = new ViewAnnotation
        {
            X1 = new DateTime(2000, 06, 01),
            Y1 = 25,
            VerticalAlignment = ChartAnnotationAlignment.Start
        };

        StackLayout layout = new StackLayout();
        Image image = new Image
        {
            Source = "Graduate.png",
            HeightRequest = 70,
            WidthRequest = 70
        };
        layout.Children.Add(image);
        annotation.View = layout;
        SfChartChartAnnotations.Add(annotation);
    }
}

And here is the corresponding XAML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="XamarinSimpleSample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:chart="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinSimpleSample">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <Grid>
        <chart:SfChart x:Name="chartannotationsample" ChartAnnotations="{Binding SfChartChartAnnotations}">
            <chart:SfChart.Title>
                <chart:ChartTitle Text="AnnotationSample" />
            </chart:SfChart.Title>

            <chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
                <chart:DateTimeAxis x:Name="XAxes" />
            </chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
            <chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
                <chart:NumericalAxis />
            </chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
            <chart:SfChart.Legend>
                <chart:ChartLegend />
            </chart:SfChart.Legend>

            <chart:LineSeries
                x:Name="series"
                EnableTooltip="True"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
                ShowTrackballInfo="True"
                XBindingPath="Date"
                YBindingPath="YValue" />

            <!--<chart:SfChart.ChartAnnotations>
                <chart:ViewAnnotation
                    x:Name="view"
                    CoordinateUnit="Axis"
                    X1="{Binding X1}"
                    Y1="{Binding Y1}">
                    <chart:ViewAnnotation.View>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Image Source="BorrowingGreen.png" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </chart:ViewAnnotation.View>
                </chart:ViewAnnotation>
            </chart:SfChart.ChartAnnotations>-->
        </chart:SfChart>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>

How can I dynamically bind the chart annotations in Syncfusion so that they reflect changes based on the count of the notes list?
